# JavaFX a shape move with mouse

Tags: canvas, javafx, mouselistener

As the image below:

[image: Sampe Image]

I choose Canvas to do a batch of drawings, I want a shape (e.g. a line) moving with the cursor to indicate the position.
First I try to erase the old line and draw a new line after the mouse move, but it would erase the overlap lines at the same time.

My question is: How to implement this function with javafx canvas.

Comment: You cannot unless you save the image without the line since `Canvas` simply stores the colors of every pixel and if your draw a line that covers some other content you loose the information about the pervious content. You could overlay the `Canvas` with a `Pane` containing a `Line` object though which whould allow you to move the line without modifying the canvas content.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I change the Cursor type to `Cursor.CROSSHAIR`, and listen to the mouseMove Event, This problem is not solved, but this workaround work for me now.